# How do I make the program return multiple table fields in a table when a button is clicked?

Tags: abap

I am trying to create a program that allows a user to input a `foodCode` in order to receive the `Item` and `Description` after the press of a button. Is there a way the results can be put in a table on the same screen? How?

```
report demo.
tables food.

SELECTION-SCREEN:

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK SEGMENTVALUE WITH FRAME TITLE A1TITLE.
SELECTION SCREEN BEGIN OF LINE.
PARAMETERS P_INPUT(10) TYPE C OBLIGATORY.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF LINE.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF LINE.
SELECTION-SCREEN PUSHBUTTON /2(40) B_RESULT USER-COMMAND BUT1.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF LINE.

INTIALIZATION.
    PERFORM SELECTION_SCREEN_TEXT.
FORM SELECTION_SCREEN TEXT.
    A1TITLE = 'Please enter food code'.
    B_RESULT = 'Return results'.
```

[image: Example Data]

Answer (score 3):

I hope I got you're question right.

1. Create a Report with a Dynpro.
2. Add a Subscreen on the top of the Dynpro and a Custom-Container on the Bottom
3. Mark your Selection-Screen as Subscreen an call the Dynpro-Number from your Selection-Screen in the PBO as Subscreen.
4. Handle the Button click in the PAI
5. Display the Data with an SALV in your CustomContainer

Here's a detailed explanation:
http://zevolving.com/2008/10/display-alv-report-output-in-the-same-selection-screen/

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do that would be yo use a Reusable alv grid that displays the results.

The function to create that look it as Reusable* alv* grid, it contains some parameters that define the screen in a table.

Comment: I think the "Is there a way the results can be put in a table on the same screen? How?" part of the question is the difficult part for OP, not just displaying the data.

Comment: I don't think that is possible in the same screen, but as above, maybe a dynpro pop-up when executing. Another solution would be to create a full Dynpro program with some select options, since it's a custom screen you'll be able to handle a table control without exiting the search screen just as the solution above