# How can you return fields after user clicks a button and put the fields into a table on the screen?

Tags: abap

I was wondering how would a program pull information from a table and display it on a screen in a table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In ABAP Workbench, how do I make the program return multiple table fields in a table when a button is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553767/in-abap-workbench-how-do-i-make-the-program-return-multiple-table-fields-in-a-t)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have example with simple report to display data from SAP in ALV table:

```
TYPE-POOLS: slis.  " SLIS contains all the ALV data types
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Data Declaration
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
DATA: it_sbook     TYPE TABLE OF sbook.
DATA: it_fieldcat  TYPE slis_t_fieldcat_alv,
      wa_fieldcat  TYPE slis_fieldcat_alv.
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& START-OF-SELECTION
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
START-OF-SELECTION.

*Fetch data from the database
  SELECT * FROM sbook INTO TABLE it_sbook.

*Build field catalog
  wa_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'CARRID'.    " Fieldname in the data table
  wa_fieldcat-seltext_m  = 'Airline'.   " Column description in the output
  APPEND wa_fieldcat TO it_fieldcat.

  wa_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'CONNID'.
  wa_fieldcat-seltext_m  = 'Con. No.'.
  APPEND wa_fieldcat TO it_fieldcat.

  wa_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'FLDATE'.
  wa_fieldcat-seltext_m  = 'Date'.
  APPEND wa_fieldcat TO it_fieldcat.

  wa_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'BOOKID'.
  wa_fieldcat-seltext_m  = 'Book. ID'.
  APPEND wa_fieldcat TO it_fieldcat.

  wa_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'PASSNAME'.
  wa_fieldcat-seltext_m  = 'Passenger Name'.
  APPEND wa_fieldcat TO it_fieldcat.

*Pass data and field catalog to ALV function module to display ALV list
  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
    EXPORTING
      it_fieldcat   = it_fieldcat
    TABLES
      t_outtab      = it_sbook
    EXCEPTIONS
      program_error = 1
      OTHERS        = 2.
```

Please also check some basic [tutorials](http://www.saphub.com/abap-tutorial/)